# Obstructing raycast with objects in scene without using an object info node. Is it possible?

Tags: camera, geometry-nodes

Basically I have a scene where i have added lens flares, but i want them to disappear when an object passes over them. So far i have been using the raycast node with an Object info node, but i would prefer to not use object info nodes because i would need to make an object info node for every object in the scene. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible right now with multiple objects.

Comment: aw man. Well thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm likely misunderstanding the question, but why not throw all objects capable of occluding the lens flare into a collection and use that to raycast instead?

[image: Raycast Collection]

Comment: Great idea!!!!